# SQL- Sorting marketing categories without table data

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, sql-server-2014, sql-view

A department store uses the following table to track sales. The data model does not include information about the floor and the category of the goods been sold.

```
CREATE TABLE A1
(    
  date      datetime,
  category  nvarchar(30),
  turnover     money  
);

INSERT INTO A1  VALUES   (SYSDATETIME(), 100, 1000);   
INSERT INTO A1  VALUES   (SYSDATETIME(), 201, 1700);
...
```

Data model/ table cannot be changed or edited. Information on the product group and floor can be diverted from the category.

```
CREATE VIEW sort_department_productgroups_view
AS
   WITH sort_department_productgroups
        AS (SELECT date,
                   category,
                   turnover,
                   CASE category
                      WHEN 100 THEN 1
                      WHEN 201 THEN 1
                      WHEN 303 THEN 1
                      WHEN 101 THEN 2
                      WHEN 102 THEN 2
                      ELSE 9
                   END
                      floor,
                   CASE category
                      WHEN 100 THEN 'sport'
                      WHEN 102 THEN 'sport'
                      WHEN 201 THEN 'leisure'
                      WHEN 303 THEN 'business'
                      WHEN 101 THEN 'sport'
                      WHEN 202 THEN 'leisure'
                      ELSE 'unknown'
                   END
                      productgroup
              FROM a1)
   SELECT *
     FROM sort_department_productgroups;

go
```

Example query on the new view:

```
SELECT * FROM sort_department_productgroups_view where productgroup='sport';
```

Are there better ways to deal with such a task? Would this work on a big database?

Comment: you can use combination of IF and IN commands

Comment: Your map of Category to Floor,Productgroup should be in another table that you join on to; this will allow better indexing and maintainability.  And the key should not be numeric as you've used in your case statements, it should be the same type as in your A1 table, nvarchar(30); so as to avoid implicit datatype conversions.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I think the syntax works on oracle and sql server exempt from the data types. I used sql server 2014 in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really crying for a lookup table. But I must admit, that a category column of type nvarchar filled with numeric values makes me wonder...

Try it like this:

#### EDIT: Changed the related columen to `NVARCHAR(30)` as OP mentioned, that this is unchangeable...

```
CREATE TABLE CATEGORY(ID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_CATEGORY PRIMARY KEY
                     ,category NVARCHAR(30)
                     ,CategoryName VARCHAR(100)
                     ,[Floor] INT );
INSERT INTO  CATEGORY VALUES
                      (100,'sport',1)
                     ,(101,'sport',2)
                     ,(102,'sport',2)
                     ,(201,'leisure',1)
                     ,(202,'leisure',9)
                     ,(303,'business',9)
                     --add more...

CREATE TABLE A1
(  
  date      datetime,
  category  NVARCHAR(30),
  turnover     money  
);

INSERT INTO A1  VALUES   (SYSDATETIME(), 100, 1000);   
INSERT INTO A1  VALUES   (SYSDATETIME(), 201, 1700);
GO

CREATE VIEW sort_department_productgroups_view
AS
SELECT A1.date
      ,a1.turnover
      ,ISNULL(CATEGORY.Floor,9) AS [Floor]
      ,ISNULL(CATEGORY.CategoryName,'unknown') AS [productgroup]
FROM A1
LEFT JOIN CATEGORY ON CATEGORY.category=A1.category;
GO

SELECT * FROM sort_department_productgroups_view
```

Comment: The op specifically states that A1 can not be changed.  This means that the INT would need to return to being an nvarchar(30).

Comment: Probably also worth showing that using a table makes it possible to make the mapping time varying (SCD2), more easily copying with a product changing which floor it is sold on...

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Shnugo that a reference table is much preferable.

I would define the view more simply as:

```
CREATE VIEW sort_department_productgroups_view AS
     SELECT date, category, turnover,
            (CASE WHEN category IN ('100', '201', '202') THEN 1
                  WHEN category IN ('101', '102') THEN 2
                  ELSE 9
             END) as floor,
            (CASE WHEN category IN ('100', '101', '102') THEN 'sport'
                  WHEN category IN ('201', '202') THEN 'leisure'
                  WHEN category IN ('303') THEN 'business'
                  ELSE 'unknown'
             END) as productgroup
     FROM a1;
```

Two important differences:

- This no longer uses a searched case, so it keeps the definition of each group in one condition.
- The values are in quotes because `category` is a string.

Finally, SQL Server allows computed columns, so you can incorporate this "column" into the table definition:

```
alter table a1
    add floor as (CASE WHEN category IN ('100', '201', '202') THEN 1
                       WHEN category IN ('101', '102') THEN 2
                       ELSE 9
                  END);
```

And similarly for the product group.

Comment: Interesting solution -  I will try the computed columns for this issue as well.